# Crie novos st.metrics para cada valor de um data frame usando laço for

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho um data frame com vários valores, deizxei apenas 3 para poder resumir onde tenho que fazer um card para cada valor exclusivo utilizando streamlit st.matric.

```
import streamlit as st

df = {"Mapa":[4568, 3265, 3456], "veiculo":["REB0125","REJ0236", "RFC5647"], "valor": [42.50, 65.30, 36.90]}

for Mapa in df["Mapa"]:
    infoMapa = Mapa
    #infoValor = valor
    #infoVeiculo = veiculo

    st.metric(
        label = "str(infoVeiculo)", 
        value = int(infoMapa),
        delta = "infoValor")
```

Imagino algo nesse sentido, seria possível fazer isso e deixar os cards de forma responsivas na linha horizontal?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.metric), você pode atribuir colunas:

```
import streamlit as st

col1, col2, col3 = st.columns(3)
col1.metric("Temperature", "70 °F", "1.2 °F")
col2.metric("Wind", "9 mph", "-8%")
col3.metric("Humidity", "86%", "4%")
```

Ficará conforme abaixo e de forma responsiva:

[image: Exemplo streamline responsivo]

Veja [aqui](https://doc-metric-example2.streamlit.app/?utm_medium=oembed)

**EDITADO**: 02/11/2023

No seu caso, acredito que o código abaixo funcione:

```
import streamlit as st

df = {"Mapa":[4568, 3265, 3456], "veiculo":["REB0125","REJ0236", "RFC5647"], "valor": [42.50, 65.30, 36.90]}

num_colunas = len(df["Mapa"])
cols = st.columns(num_columns)

for idx, Mapa in enumerate(df["Mapa"]):
    infoMapa = Mapa

    col = cols[idx]
    col.metric(
        label = "str(infoVeiculo)", 
        value = int(infoMapa),
        delta = "infoValor")
```

Comment: Boa noite Paulo, alguma ideia de como aplicar o for nas columns e trazer as 3 informações?

Comment: @LuisMarra, veja se confere com suas necessidades

Comment: Boa noite, quase que confere, tem mais 2 situações que preciso resolver.

**1a) quando faz o for todas as colunas ficam na mesma linha e ajustando a janela ele joga todos os metric na col1**
_|_
**2a) tentei fazer o iterrows no for, então...

`de: for idx, Mapa in enumerate(df["Mapa"]):`
`para: for idx, rows in enumerate(df.iterrows()):`

pra poder acessar os outras colunas como rows.Mapa, rows.veiculo e rows.valor**

mas ainda ta dando errado...

Comment: Pelo visto você está usando `pandas`, certo? Isso não estava no seu post.

Comment: Boa tarde, isso mesmo. Tenho um data frame grande aqui... tem muita coisa legal que consegui fazer com as tabelas olhando videos e tutoriais, mas esses desafios com streamlit ta sendo grande....

ajustando essa questão do st.metric ja passo pro proximo desafio que vai ser gerar o pdf...